# MIPS calculator not outputting properly

Tags: math, mips, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to implement a MIPS calculator that takes 3 ints as input and returns an output. Currently, the code outputs "The sum of int1, int2, and int3 is 1" and I don't understand why. Perhaps I haven't written the addition subroutine properly?

```
        .data
welc:   .asciiz "Enter an integer:\n"
sum:    .asciiz "The sum of "
prod:   .asciiz "The product of "
divi:   .asciiz "The quotient of "
subt:   .asciiz "The difference of "
also:   .asciiz " and "
comma:  .asciiz ", "
rem:    .asciiz "remainder:"
is:     .asciiz " is "

int1:   .word 1 #space to hold first int
int2:   .word 1 #space to hold second int
int3:   .word 1 #space to hold third int
input:  .space 1 #space to hold raw input
out:    .word 1 #space to hold output
remain: .word 1 #space to hold remainder

        .text
        .globl main
main :  li $v0, 4       #syscall 4, print string
        la $a0, welc    #give argument: string "Enter an integer:"
        syscall

        li $v0, 5   #tell syscall we want to read int 1
        syscall
        la $s1, int1    #load int1 into $s1
        sw $v0, 0($s1)  #copy int from $v0 to int 1

        li $v0, 4   #syscall 4, print string
        la $a0, welc    #give argument: string "Enter an integer:"
        syscall

        li $v0, 5   #tell syscall we want to read int 2
        syscall
        la $s2, int2    #load int2 into $s2
        sw $v0, 0($s2)  #copy int from $v0 to int 2

        li $v0, 4   #syscall 4, print string
        la $a0, welc    #give argument: string "Enter an integer:"
        syscall

        li $v0, 5   #tell syscall we want to read int 3
        syscall
        la $s3, int3    #load int3 into $s3
        sw $v0, 0($s3)  #copy int from $v0 to int 3

        la $s0, out #load output to $s0

        j plus  #jump to calc

plus:   add $s0, $s1, $s2   #add int1 and int2 and put in out
        add $s0, $s0, $s3   #add out and int3

        li $v0, 4   #tell syscall to print string
        la,$a0, sum #print sum string
        syscall
        li $v0, 1   #tell syscall to print int
        la $s1, int1    #tell syscall to print int1
        lw $a0, 0($s1)  #load int 1 into $a0 and print
        syscall
        li $v0, 4   #tell syscall to print string
        la,$a0, comma   #tell syscall to print comma
        syscall
        li $v0, 1   #tell syscall to print int
        la $s2, int2    #tell syscall to print int2
        lw $a0, 0($s2)  #load int 2 into $a0 and print
        syscall
        li $v0, 4   #tell syscall to print string
        la,$a0, comma   #tell syscall to print comma
        syscall
        li $v0, 4   #tell syscall to print string
        la,$a0, also    #tell syscall to print comma
        syscall
        li $v0, 1   #tell syscall to print int
        la $s3, int3    #tell syscall to print int3
        lw $a0, 0($s3)  #load int 3 into $a0 and print
        syscall
        li $v0, 4   #tell syscall to print string
        la,$a0, is  #tell syscall to print is
        syscall
        li $v0, 1   #tell syscall to print int
        la $s0, out #tell syscall to print output
        lw $a0, 0($s0)
        syscall

        li $v0, 10  #exit code
        syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$s0`, `$s1`, and `$s2` you have addresses. Therefore in `$s0` you have the sum of addresses which is not want you want. Also, you're outputting the value at `out`, which you never changed.

Before you add the numbers, you must load their value with `lw`. Then, if you want to print the value at `out`, you have to store `$s0` at that address first.